# Is there way prevent Limits for sending & getting mail using gmail smtp?

Tags: laravel, gmail

I have problem regarding Expected response code 354 but got code "550", with message "550 5.4.5 Daily user sending quota exceeded. k32sm18267425pjc.36 - gsmtp " this happens when I send email from other. I used gmail as a unpaid gmail account. based on their help support contents, is it because the daily usage limit.? this is the first time I encounter this error when I test the mailing function of my project.

Technology Use: Laravel 5.7 Version

**Question:**

1. Do I need to pay to the gmail so that there is no limit sending email from other user?
2. Is there need to configure to the gmail to prevent this error?

**Problem:**

> Expected response code 354 but got code "550", with message "550 5.4.5 Daily user sending quota exceeded. k32sm18267425pjc.36 - gsmtp "

Here is the smaple Code:

```
       $data = [
            'branch' => $client_branch,
            'email' => $client_email,
            'subject' => 'Finance Approval'
        ];

        
        Mail::send('new_franchising_payment',['data'=>$data], function ($m) use ($data) {

            $m->from('example@gmail.com', $data['subject']);
            $m->to('example2@gmail.com')
            ->subject('You have new notification!');

        });
```

.ENV File

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=just secret
MAIL_PASSWORD=just secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Very well appreciate your response guys!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the free tariff plan has a limit on the number of messages sent. At the paid level, there will already be other limits.
All information can be found in the official documentation from google

https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491#sendinglimitsforrelay